# I Want to Diversify Solr Results

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working on a search application for apparel and I'm having a problem with results from the same brand bunching together. So for example I'll get 6 results from brand A, followed by 7 results from brand B, followed by 4 results from brand C. I have a feature where I boost results for particular brands based on user preferences and the bunching is occuring when I invoke this feature. I want to diversify the results so the boosted brands are mixed up.

I can't use the grouping (or field collapsing) feature because I don't want to conceal results.

The request handler that I'm using in solrconfig.xml looks like this:

```xml
<requestHandler name="products" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="qf">title^2.0 description^1.7 details^1.5 color_name^1.3 category_name^1.3</str>
       <str name="fl">*</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The code that I'm using to boost the brands at query time (in Solrj) looks something like this:

```java
query.setParam("bq", "brand_id:(29 11 53 8 27 30)^0.1");
```

(The numbers in this snippet are brand ids.)

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you sort the results by brand? Then you would negate all boosting.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Even when I remove sorting, I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: Possibly the brand name occurs in the title or any other of the fields, so that the other boost factors do the "sorting"?